# In the Visual Studio SQL editor, how do I get rid of the boxes?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-scripts

I usually create my SQL tables and stored procedures by writing a script inside Visual Studio. This works really well for me except for one simple annoyance: VS puts blue boxes around all the SQL queries and data-manipulation commands. The purpose of these boxes is to draw undue attention to the fact that VS thinks the query can be edited in “Query Builder.”

I don’t want to use Query Builder. I just want a nice, clean script that reflects my fantastic vision of what the DB engine should do. Blast it, Jim, I’m a programmer not a Microsoft Access hobbyist!

I do, however, like the syntax highlighting and source-control integration that VS provides.

So my question is this: How do I turn off the annoying blue boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color of the SQL query outline to the same color as the background.

Answer (score 6):

Open Visual Studio Tools --> options --> Database Tools --> General. Uncheck "Enable DML Markers"

Comment: Note that this option is not applied to currently open files.