# Remove strange blue box in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

[image: Bluebox microsoft devilspawn]

This blue rectangle is fixed on the screen. Sometimes growing, shrinking and changing place.

tried the answer to this question: 
[In the Visual Studio SQL editor, how do I get rid of the boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270005/in-the-visual-studio-sql-editor-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-boxes)
as I thought it might be related but didn't help.
How to get rid of it?

Comment: If you go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General and change the Color Theme to something else, does it go away or does it remain?

Comment: This is not a VS feature.  Disable add-ins one by one.

Comment: it might be worth mentioning that it was running in parallels on mac os. Not really an answer to the question but restarting the windows instance on parallels removed it.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The box is drawn by [Windows' Narrator feature](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hear-text-read-aloud-narrator) for people with low vision. I recently accidentally toggled this myself by hitting <kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. Hitting it again and moving the mouse cursor seems to toggle it back off again as well.

As mentioned below, depending on the narrator shortcuts configured on your system one of the following may work:

- <kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.
- <kbd>caps lock</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>

Full overview of narrator hot keys [can be found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22806/windows-10-narrator-keyboard-commands-touch-gestures).

Comment: Thank you! I accidentally did this and couldn't figure out what I had done.

Comment: Cheers. I knew I hit the windows key just, but could not work out which over key I hit to trigger this.

Comment: This needs to be marked as the correct answer, this was driving me nuts!

Comment: Thanks! You just saved my nite!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Not sure if it is limited to running windows 10 in VM on mac but if CMD + Enter does not hide the Narrator block you can disable Narrator in Ease of Access settings -> Narrator. In my case after disabling Narrator the blue block still showed and I had to kill the Narrator process in Task manager.

Comment: See below, for alternative - CapsLock + Esc

Answer (score 4):

For some reason Winkey + Enter didn't work for me. However I found Caps Lock + Esc did the trick. See [Narrator Shortcuts](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/narrator-magnifier-keyboard-shortcuts) for more info

Comment: tHIS WORKED FOR ME

Answer (score -7):

It looks like you have an extension installed which is adding that box.  Try disabling extensions until you find the one that is causing this

- Tools -> Options -> Extension Manager